# How to select the inside of a folder before doing Wscript.shell send Keys?

Tags: powershell, sendkeys, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to automate opening a folder (maximized) selecting all files, I also need to expand all columns.

I'm able to do all those things, but I'm having a small issue, if someone could help me with it that would be great.

If I do this:

```
Start 'path' -WindowStyle Maximized
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.sendKeys]::SendWait("^{a}")
[System.Windows.Forms.sendKeys]::SendWait("%{v}{s}{f}")
```

Then the `alt + v + s + f` is not working properly it shows up for a split second and it's gone and sf are not pressed or activated, but the `ctrl + a` is working good.

So to get around that I'm doing this:

```
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wsh.AppActivate('Name of window')
$wsh.sendKeys("%{v}{s}{f}")
```

Now this is doing the `alt + v + s + f` fine but the `ctrl + a` becomes greyed out (by greyed out I mean the selected files are in grey instead of blue which is for actively selected files), probably because that selects the frame of window instead of the inside? I'm not sure, if I try to do a `ctrl + a` with Wscript it's not doing anything, so I can only do it before declaring `$wsh`.
And I am waiting before and after keys for a 3 seconds as well.

I'm using windows 10. But writing to be used in server 2016.

Any ideas how to fix this behavior?

Edit:

> the first version is working fine on my personal laptop with windows 10 version 2004, but not working as expected on server 2016 version 1607

Comment: Your initial script works fine for me if I add `Start-Sleep -Seconds 1` after `start 'path'`

Comment: You are able to expand columns with that one? For me ```alt v s f was not working``` I will try again but I did try it a few times yesterday.

Comment: Yeah you are right it does work on my windows 10 fine, only not working on sever 2016 v1607, but that's where the automation will be useful :(